# Uniswap V3 out of Price Range and Range Order

Tags: swap, cryptocurrency, decentralized-applications

I am confused with concept of range order and price range set in Uniswap.

1. Is range order put from user side while trying to order a swap? or set in LP side?
2. Regarding of the price range, from the documents I read, my understanding is that LP can put a price range for providing the liquidity, if the price shifts out of the range, that LP's liquidity will be not entitle for the swap order thus no earning i made. In this scenario I think the asset should be locked, the 'My' 2 tokens' allocation should be kept until the price falls into my range. Is this the case? In my exercise all my ETH convert to USDC while the market price move out my range, why does this happen?

Thanks,
S